# Laravel resource route parameters not overriding

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-8

I am building a Laravel 8 api. I'm trying to set up a show route for `/api/access-type/{access_type}`. I want to change the `{access_type}` to be `{id}`

This is the route definition:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:api'])->group(function () {

    /////////// not allowed to use these. Creating/deleting these resources would require code changes
    Route::apiResource(
        \App\Http\Controllers\AccessTypeController::$uri,
        'AccessTypeController'
    )->only(['index', 'show'])->parameters(['access_type' => 'id']);
});
```

When I look at the listed routes I can see that the route hasn't changed:

```
GET|HEAD | api/access-types/{access_type} | access-types.show | App\Http\Controllers\AccessTypeController@show | Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful | Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests:api | Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:api
```

If I use postman to visit `/api/access-types/3` I can see that there is no `$request->id` variable, but there is a `$request->access_type` variable, so the overwrite isn't working. What am I doing wrong? This should work according to: [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters)

Comment: Could you try `['access_types' => 'id']`

Comment: Hi @Remul, no luck with that

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it with the following:

```
Route::apiResource(
    \App\Http\Controllers\AccessTypeController::$uri,
    'AccessTypeController'
)->parameters(['access-types' => 'id']);
```

The parameter had to match the uri that I was setting it up for. I suppose this is so you can group multiple different resource routes into one.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it on laravel version 10 with the following:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\OrderController;

Route::apiResource("orders", OrderController::class)
   ->parameters(['orders' => 'order_number'])
    ->only(['show','store','update']);
```